# how to set class names in list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have five HTML li elements. Let's say if the 3rd li element has the active class, then I want the 1st and 2nd li element to have class complete. First remove the class whatever 1st and 2nd li element has, then add the class complete.
If the 3rd li element has class name active, then the 4th li element should have half-complete class name. The last li element should have nothing.

```
<ul>
  <li class="complete">Coffee</li>
  <li class="complete">Tea</li>
  <li class="active">Milk</li>
  <li class="hafl-complete">Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: please share the code you try with

Comment: could you explain the concept? for example, do you mean ALL li elements BEFORE the class `active` li should have class `complete`? and if so what's the rule for the elements after?

Comment: Will the list always have 5 elements?  Why does the 5th element have no class?  That looks unusual.  Does the word hafl mean something or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li class="something1">Coffee</li>
    <li class="something2">Tea</li>
    <li class="something">Milk</li>
    <li class="something3">Milk</li>
    <li class="delivered">Milk</li>
</ul>


  let deliveredParent = document.querySelector(". delivered").parentElement;
  let children = [...deliveredParent.children];
  for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    let child = children[i];
    if(child.classList.contains("delivered")) break;
    child.className = "complete";
  }
```

Note:
"half-completed" is no longer added.

Comment: may I asked one more question lets say if last li has delivered class how to make first 4 li to have only class complete ? if 5th li has class delivered I want 1st 2nd 3rd 4th li to have class complete ???

Comment: well my code would not work if the last li is active, in that case you need to use a if statement to check it.

Comment: not talking about active class if last li having class name delivered ı want rest of li (1st 2nd 3rd 4th) to have class complete

Comment: just change the active to delivered and inside the if statement just change it to break. And finally remove the last if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `jQuery` solution.

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $('ul li').removeClass('active complete hafl-complete');
  
  $(this).prevAll('ul li').addClass('complete');
  $(this).addClass('active').next('ul li').removeClass('complete').addClass('hafl-complete');
  
  console.log($('ul').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="complete">Coffee</li>
  <li class="complete">Tea</li>
  <li class="active">Milk</li>
  <li class="hafl-complete">Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually scenario is something like that from api I will get what progress I am in right now let say I am in 4th level right so 1st and 2nd level will have class completed 3rd will have active class 4th will have half-complete class it should be like that

Comment: @mrtyvz61, those, do you want to get `hafl-complete` on the `li` on which the click occurred?

Comment: its not about clicking on li its all about what api response to me about level if its 4th level then hanf-complete class will be at 4th li then 3rd li will be active class then 1st and 2nd class will have complete class got it my friend ?

Comment: Not about clicking?  How does the api know when to respond?